# BIDS Data Mining Performance Issue

Tags: sql, ssis, data-mining, bids

I'm having an interesting problem with Microsoft Business Intelligence Development Studio and the Data Mining Query Task.  I have a package in which there are (among a few other things) two Data Mining Query Tasks, which take in some rows from an already existing database, perform the data mining query on them, and append them to the same database.  Both databases are moderately small (on the order of 30,000 rows with about 15 columns).

This was all well and good on the development server, but I'm running into a weird issue as I try to shift everything to the production environment.  After a specific and consistent number of rows in each database, the Data Mining Query Tasks hangs (the numbers are 2001 for the first task and 5001 for the second task).  Any number of rows less than these limits and it takes a few seconds.  Anything longer and the Task times out (after 2 hours).

Another thing to note is that when I pull information from the same production databases but insert them into a different table on the development server, everything goes fine.

I can only assume there is some setting in the production database that is messing something up, but I don't have a clue what it could be.  Unforunately, I am only an intern and didn't set up the system, nor do I have complete access to everything, but I did some poking around and couldn't find any material differences in the settings.

Anyone have any advice or suggestions?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks for the reply. I have selected the table under the Build New Query window. I don't think the actual case table is the issue however, because the Package executes fine when I change the output table to a table on a different server. Here is a stripped down version of the query I use:

```
SELECT FLATTENED

  t.field1,  
  t.field2,  
  t.field3,  
  t.field4,  
  t.field5,  
  t.field6,  
  t.field7,  
  t.field8,  
  t.field9,  
  t.field10,  
  t.field11,  
  t.field12,  
  t.field13,  
  t.field14,  
  t.field15,  
  t.field16,  
  t.field17,  
  t.field18,  
  t.field19,  
  ([MiningModel].[Model Output Column]) as field20,  
  PredictProbability([Model Output Column])  
From  
  [MiningModel]  
PREDICTION JOIN  
  OPENQUERY([Input Table Data Source],  
    'SELECT  
     field1,  
    field2,  
    field3,  
    field4,  
    field5,  
    field6,  
    field7,  
    field8,  
    field9,  
    field10,  
    field11,  
    field12,  
    field13,  
    field14,  
    field15,  
    field16,  
    field17,  
    field18,  
    field19,  
    field 20  
    FROM  
      [Input Table]  
    ') AS t  
ON  
  [MiningModel].[Model Input 1] = t.[field16] AND  
  [MiningModel].[Model Input 2] = t.[field17] AND  
  [MiningModel].[Model Input 3] = t.[field18] AND  
  [MiningModel].[Model Input 4] = t.[field19] AND  
  [MiningModel].[Model Output Column] = t.[field20]
```

Comment: You can't really expect people to attempt to answer this without knowing what the data mining queries are.  In particular, how is bids pulling the data from the database?  It sounds like a query or view is being used, rather than a raw table.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a profiler and capture errors, do you see [Sort Warnings](http://www.solidq.com/sqj/Pages/Relational/Identifying-and-Solving-Sort-Warnings-Problems-in-SQL-Server.aspx)?

Can you identify any incorrect statistics? 
Maybe the problem goes away after:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS InputTable WITH FULLSCAN, ALL
```